# Adding dojo parameter to exsisting field

Tags: javascript, dojo, textfield

I have a form created in php and I want to add some attributes to it from js dojo.

I can retrive the textfield by it's id (dojo.byId), but how to add the placeholder attribute to the node without creating a new one and replacing the previous field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dojo.byId("textbox1").placeholder = "I'm your placeholder";
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/ww98a/